# How to join two pieces of rope in an adjustable tight loop?

Tags: mountaineering, wild-camping, knots, hammock

I'm looking to use a piece of paracord as a ridge/sag line in my hammock setup, to do this I want to be able to tie the two ends together in a fashion that will allow me to alter the length of the loop easily but to lock in place - this knot will be taking my weight and my gears overnight so it needs to be solid.

Comment: A taut-line hitch is a possibility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taut-line_hitch

Comment: You don't normally do that but you would see others using a double figure eight with the ends knotted.  http://www.animatedknots.com/fig8join/index.php?Categ=rescue&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how your setup is, but I'd try a Purcell prussik or something similar.

[Animated example](http://www.animatedknots.com/purcell/#ScrollPoint)

You must test its holding Power on paracord yourself, but on climbing cord it's solid enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this out and mark it as the correct answer if it works :)

Comment: With smaller cord you just need to use more wraps if it's not holding.

Comment: True, though there is a practical limit to the number of wraps. Also cord diameter isn't Everything. Sheath material also matters.

Comment: @Guran if you're using a Klenheist or Bachmann hitch, then there's no practical limit to the number of loops.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do what you're looking for. One way I solve this problem is with a metal ring. You attach a fixed knot on the ring, pass one end of the rope through one loop of the hammock, wrap the rope 3-4 times through the ring and then a fixed knot on the other loop of the hammock. Slide the ring up and down the ridgeline to adjust the size.

[Dutchgear](http://www.dutchwaregear.com/structural-and-adjustable-ridgelines.html) has an image of this setup.
[image: Dutchgear pic 3]

Comment: To begin as a good solution the knot on the left should be a bowline, not sure what it is, but it is not safe.

Comment: I didn't create the image, (its available in the attached link). That being said, a bowline wouldn't be a good knot either as its not constricting. A buntline would be better.

Answer (score 3):

The type of knot you are looking for a called a **friction hitch**, or a [slide and grip knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/indextypeslidegrip.php?LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint) which is a kind of knot used to attach one rope to another in a way that is easily adjusted.

There are many different ways to tie a friction hitch:

- [Klemheist](http://www.animatedknots.com/klemheist/index.php?Categ=typehitches&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint)
- [Blake's Hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/blakes/index.php?Categ=typehitches&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint)
- [Distel Hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/distel/index.php?Categ=typehitches&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint)
- [Rolling Hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/rollinghitch/index.php?Categ=typehitches&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint)
- [Prussic](http://www.animatedknots.com/prusik/index.php?Categ=typehitches&LogoImage=LogoGrog.png&Website=www.animatedknots.com#ScrollPoint)
- [Bachmann Hitch](http://dyeclan.com/outdoors101/canyoneering101/?page=bachmann-hitch)
- [Autoblock Hitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4umuoQeggo)

And of course the Purcell Prusik, but the Purcell Prusik was developed for ascending ropes and doing rescue work, it may be a bit complicated to your purposes.